# How to save image as stream?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a screenshot and send it from C# to PHP where I store it.

I create a screenshot like this:

```
Bitmap screenshot = TakeScreenshot();
```

Now I try to [save it as a stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Stream myStream;  
screenshot.Save(myStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

However, I get `Use of unassigned local variable 'myStream'`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Functions:**

```
private Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
{
    //Create a new bitmap.
    var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
    using (var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
    {    
        // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0,
                                0,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);    
    }

    return bmpScreenshot;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize your stream before using it.

```
using (MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    screenshot.Save(myStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
}
```

Comment: Points for `using` to close and dispose the stream.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - Although it is good to be consistent you do not have to dispose a `MemoryStream` instance, there are no unmanaged resources that need to be released. If you look at the `Dispose` implementation in `MemoryStream` nothing actually happens.

Answer (score 4):

By `Stream` you mean `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`, what? Whatever the case, just initialize the variable to be the proper kind of stream you need.

For example:

```
using(var myStream = new MemoryStream())
{....}
```